# How could I find a relative path needed in using Sharpdevelop Software

Tags: installation, setuptools, enterprise-architect, sharpdevelop

I am using Sharpdevelop as an installer , and in fact I have installed my files in 
**`C:\Program Files`**

but my question that I need to install all my files inside an specific path :
for example :
I would like to install it in :
**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\MyFolder`**
It is mandatory to install in this path,

I did some configurations in Files.wxs like :

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="xchangeTools">
                  ....
                  ....
                  ....

               </Directory>
           </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
```

So I need some script or code to help me to retrieve the relative path of Sparx Systems Directory,
I hope this is very clear , 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect's install location can be retrieved from the registry key value `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\Install Path`.